# Determine the expected value of the random variable

Tags: probability

If $X$ is a random variable s.t. take the values $-1$, $0$, $1$ and $2$ with

$$P(X=0)=0.1, \quad P(X=1)=0.4, \quad P(X=2)=\frac{1}{2} P(X=-1)$$

we know that

$$E(X) = 0(0.1)+1(0.4)+2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot P(X=-1)$$

It seems that this value gives $0.4$, but to find the unknown probability I thought about solving for

$$P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=-1)+P(X=2)=1$$

But is this expression valid in this context?

Comment: Yeah that's the right idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, but you didn't take into account -1 when computing the expectation.
it should be:
$$E(X)=0(0.1)+1(0.4)+2⋅\frac{1}{2}⋅P(X=−1)-1⋅P(X=-1)$$